# Unity - specify custom package path using SSH

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

We can specify package path within repository using HTTPS in Unity's `manifest.json` like that:

```
"dependencies": {
    "com.mycompany.mypackage1": "https://github.example.com/myuser/myrepository.git?path=/subfolder1",
    "com.mycompany.mypackage3": "https://github.example.com/myuser/myrepository.git?path=/subfolder2/subfolder3"
  }
```

Is it possible to specify package path using `SSH` protocol? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes it is possible](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#Git-SSH)

If you happen to need a specific path or revision it gets slightly tricky. There is the optional [revision](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#revision) and or [`path`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#subfolder) arguments.

However, from [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/some-feedback-on-package-manager-git-support.743345/#post-8444525)

> It works with SSH URLs but not when they are in the SCP-like format,
> which, unfortunately, is the format that is given by most (all?) major
> Git repository hosting services like Github.com for SSH access.
>
> You can easily convert the SCP-like form to a standard SSH URL by
> doing two changes to the original string (both changes are required):
>
> - Replace the colon (`:`) between the server name and repo path with a forward slash (`/`)
> - Prefix the result with `ssh://`
>
> For example: [image]
>
> The resulting `ssh://...` URL should work with the optional path and revision features.

So I think in your case this should do

```
"dependencies": {
    "com.mycompany.mypackage1": "ssh://git@github.example.com/myuser/myrepository.git?path=/subfolder1",
    "com.mycompany.mypackage3": "ssh://git@github.example.com/myuser/myrepository.git?path=/subfolder2/subfolder3"
}
```